# queries on plist in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

hi I heard that plist is same as database  in iOS, the question is hitting in my mind is that can we execute DML DDL etc statements on plist, if yes simple example will be appreciated, if no means, why? I m fresher in iOS development.

Thank You.

Comment: If you are searching for sqlite, you can find a sample code on this link ---   http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "No".

You can use Sqlite for executing these statements.

**Property Lists**
A plist is simply a list of nested key-value pairs which can contain common data types like Strings, Numbers, Arrays and Dictionaries.

**Pros**

- Simple to understand.
- Easy to work with.

**Cons**

Cannot run complex queries on them (at least not easily).
You have to read the entire file into memory to get any data out of it and save the entire file to modify anything in it.

**SQLite**
Until CoreData came along, this was the popular way to read and write data in iPhone applications. If your a web developer, this ain’t nothing new.
**Pros**

- Unlike plists, you don’t have to load the whole database up front.
  This makes SQLite more suitable for applications with lots of data.
- Better than plists for slicing and dicing data.

**Cons**

Steeper learning curve than plists.
Can get tedious to work with.

**Core Data**

Its new, its exciting, and its probably what most developers will use from here on out.

I have not spent enough time with CoreData to summarize it; check out the tutorials (below) to learn more about it.

**Pros**

- Nearly all the benefits of SQLite with a lot less hassle (Apple does
  a lot of the dirty work for you).
- As Apple’s preferred method it has a lot more official documentation and sample code (it seems the articles and sample code for the other two methods have mysteriously disappeared from Apple’s website).

**Cons**

- Steeper learning curve than plists.
- Killer: only works on iPhone OS >3.0. Its killer if your market consists largely of iPod Touch users (who have to pay for upgrades).

Answer (score 1):

> I heard that plist is same as database in iOS

You heard wrong. A plist is not a database.

> an we execute DML DDL etc statements on plist

Not directly, no. A plist, or *property list*, is simply one way of serializing certain kinds of objects, not unlike a JSON file. To use a plist, you normally first deserialize it, resulting in an object graph which you can then examine.

You can read all about property lists in Apple's [*Property List Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html).